# How to define an aspectj pointcut that picks out all constructors of a class that has a specific annotation?

Tags: constructor, annotations, aspectj, pointcut

Here is the annotation:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String name();
}
```

Here is one annotated class:

```
@MyAnnotation(name="foo")
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Here is a second annotated class:

```
@MyAnnotation(name="bar")
public class ClassB {
    public ClassB(String aString) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I am looking for an aspectj pointcut that correctly matches the constructors for ClassA and ClassB while not matching any other constructor for any other class NOT annotated by `MyAnnotation`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pointcut should look like this:

```java
execution((@MyAnnotation *).new(..))
```

If the annotation is in another package:

```java
execution((@de.scrum_master.aop.demo.MyAnnotation *).new(..))
```

Or if you do not want to fully qualify the package:

```java
execution((@*..MyAnnotation *).new(..))
```

---

**Edit:** Okay, some more info about your question in the comment:

Constructor executions have no return value which you could capture in

```java
after() returning(Object myObject) : myJoinpoint()
```

This only works for methods. So please use

```java
after(Object myObject) returning : myJoinpoint() && this(myObject)
```

instead if you do need the constructed object for any purpose.

Comment: Have you tried this? I ask because I tried defining execution join points on constructors and the result was a warning that it cannot be applied. The documentation provides syntax for constructor pointcut primitives using a call(), but not an execution() equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. I even replicated your classes and annotation locally and wrote a driver class with a main method instantiating objects.

Comment: If you like, go to my homepage (check my profile), find the online chat and exchange e-mail addresses with me. Maybe I can help you if I see the full code. Or just use the contact form. Oh, by the way: Have you seen the inner brackets?

Comment: Thank you. Then my problem extends beyond this simple example. Here is a trivial advice that I used:


    after() returning (Object x): execution(*.new()) {
        // testing
    }

Here is the warning message:

    advice defined in com.corp.experimental.AnnotationTests has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

I have since achieved success by using a combination of pointcut primitives starting with initialization(), but your solution is more direct and cleaner. I will post the approach I took a bit later as an alternative. Regardless, I wish to work out my problems in using yours.

Comment: The lack of qualification with annotations in the previous example is intentional.

Comment: Just remove the unused "Object x" within the brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your patience on this. No warning on compile. I now get a "org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException" for --> after() returning: execution(*.new()) { // things to do }

Comment: I have updated my answer. But sorry, this discussion ends here. Contact me as suggested and let me see your full code. With tiny bits of information we will not get far, only spam the discussion here.

Comment: Agreed and once more, thank you for your time. I submitted a contact me form on your site to continue offline.

Comment: The working solution kruegaex is represented in its entirety "below".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working solution from kriegaex in its entirety:

```
public aspect AnnotationTests {
  public aspect AnnotationTests {
    after(Object myObject) returning : execution((@MyAnnotation *).new(..))
        && this(myObject) {
      System.out.println("Object class name: " + myObject.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}

@MyAnnotation(name="foo")
public class ClassA {
  public ClassA() {
    // Do something
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB("");
    if (classA.getClass().getName().equals(classB.getClass().getName())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Big problems!");
    }
  }
}

@MyAnnotation(name="bar")
public class ClassB {
  private final String aString;

  public ClassB(String aString) {
    this.aString = aString;
  }
}
```

Comment: This IS your solution. The only difference between this and the many fragments above is it is represented here in its entirety. I can only guess that there is some value to having me check your response. If this is the case, please copy and paste it into your response above and I will happily remove this one and check yours again.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my "selected" answer so you receive the recognition you deserve.

Answer (score 0):

THE FOLLOWING WORKS, BUT IS NOT RECOMMENDED BY kriegaex. PROVIDED HERE AS POSSIBLE MATERIAL THAT COULD BE REPURPOSED IF THE NEED ARISES.

This was my first working solution to the problem which uses in part the initialization() pointcut primitive.

```
public aspect AnnotationTests {
  private pointcut genericConstructor(): initialization(*.new(..));
  private pointcut withinMyAnnotation(): @within(MyAnnotation);
  private pointcut constructorInAnnotatedClass(): genericConstructor()
      && withinMyAnnotation();

  before(): constructorInAnnotatedClass() && !cflowbelow(constructorInAnnotatedClass()) {
    final Object objectInstance = thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
    System.out.println("Object class name at join point: "
        + objectInstance.getClass().getName());
  }
}

@MyAnnotation(name="foo")
public class ClassA {
  public ClassA() {
    // Do something
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB("");
    if (classA.getClass().getName().equals(classB.getClass().getName())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Big problems!");
    }
  }
}

@MyAnnotation(name="bar")
public class ClassB {
  private final String aString;

  public ClassB(String aString) {
    this.aString = aString;
  }
}
```