# How can I use AOP to intercept the constructor of File, FileReader, FileWriter, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I want to intercept the constructor of File, FileReader, FileWriter, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream and prevent any filenames from containing ".." (to prevent path traversal attacks) or "\0" (to prevent filename null character attacks).

I have another open question about how to do this same thing using SecurityManager, but no one has answered it yet, so I was hoping this alternate method would work.

This is for a spring webapp on tomcat.

I know that I could manually do this by making my own SafeFile, SafeFileReader, etc., classes and modifying the code to use those instead. However, there are 960 places in our code that use the constructors for those objects, so I'd prefer to avoid that unless it's the only way.

Comment: Do you have 960 services which accept a file path as an argument? While you may have 960 places which interact with files, is the source of the path truly untrustworthy everywhere?

Comment: Instead of using a heavy approach as AOP for this isn't it easier to use a factory to create the files. Modify the 960 places to use that factory and you solved it without aspects. Modifying all those places shouldn't be to hard to refactor. Ofcourse you could do anything you want with AspectJ and modify the classes you mentioned using loadtime weaving (not with plain Spring AOP) but it feels like using a cannon to kill a fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the answer linked to here by Sotirios Delimanolis is correct (I wrote it myself) insofar as AspectJ instead of proxy-based Spring AOP is necessary, please note that you cannot use `execution(*.new(..))` for JDK classes because those are excluded from aspect weaving by default. In order to weave into JDK classes (execution joinpoints are logically in the callee code) you need to modify the JDK's rt.jar or at least put the modified JDK classes on the bootclasspath before the JDK itself. This is possible, but not so trivial.

But there is a simpler option: weave into the callers (your own code), not the callees via `call(*.new(..))` - note the difference between `call()` and `execution()`. This in turn means that you cannot intercept calls to JDK classes not made from your own woven code or from the JDK itself. So if you need a 100% solution even for code not under your own control, you will end up weaving the JDK. Probably this is not necessary though if you just want to secure your own classes. :-)

As much as I am a huge fan of AspectJ, I want to highlight that I am also a firm proponent of clean code and refactoring. Any decent IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse should make it quite simple to refactor 960 calls to use a safe wrapper class like you suggested. Why do you not do this if it is so important? IDEA's structural search and replace does that for you in minutes, if not seconds. AOP can, but should not be used to patch up your own code's deficiencies. So please go refactor, you will be much happier afterwards.

Comment: FWIW, since you knew how to do it with aop and then said I should refactor anyway, I went ahead and just did the refactor. I feel bad for the QA department, but it's certainly simple to understand this way.

Answer (score 2):

[Simple Spring AOP (with proxying) does not support constructor join points.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn)

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans).

If you can go with `aspectj`, [that should do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184391/how-to-define-an-aspectj-pointcut-that-picks-out-all-constructors-of-a-class-tha). Otherwise, you'll have to play with bytecode yourself.