# Spring AOP pointcut on instance creation of a class

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I have a class annotated with `@Tool`. I'd love to run some kind of initializing aspect over it as soon as it is created. I have not found any documentation on how to wire to this particular event.

I thought about annotating the class constructor but that is kinda explicit. I'd love to have some more *magic* and therefore have a pointcut implicitly like wiring up to the default CTOR usage or something.

Please provide me with some documentation/tutorial since I just cannot find any because I lack on the proper keywords to search for it.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, @xetra11. So where is your code, your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You already received a close vote from someone else and can expect to get more. But for now I can already tell you that Spring AOP will not help you here. In order to intercept constructor calls or executions or even static class initialisation (right after class-loading), you need to use full-blown AspectJ, which you can either use independent of or from within Spring. I will provide more details after you do.

Comment: that information already is good for me. Could not figure out AspectJ is the way to go here. And about  the code in my question: I'm sure I don't need to provide a minimum working snippet for every question here. Sometimes normal words should be enough to understand the question

Comment: Maybe a `BeanPostProcessor` is what you are looking for. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use AOP to intercept the constructor of File, FileReader, FileWriter, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398260/how-can-i-use-aop-to-intercept-the-constructor-of-file-filereader-filewriter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398260/how-can-i-use-aop-to-intercept-the-constructor-of-file-filereader-filewriter), you have to use actual aspectj instead of just spring-aop to intercept constructor calls.